# como inserir imagem no banco de dados

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql, imagem, lua

Que tipo de variável eu uso para armazenar uma imagem no banco de dados? E existe um comando especifico para isso? ou é só inserir como um registro qualquer?

eu tenho um projeto na linguagem lua ( mobile pelo corona sdk )que a pessoa tem que tirar uma foto e preciso salvar essa foto no banco do PostgreSQL

Eu tenho uma tabela de publicacao com os campos:

código, localidade, hora, descricao ,categoria, imagem na imagem eu pretendo armazenar uma foto tirada pelo usuario.

sabendo que do celular vai ser enviado para o web service que vai adicionar no banco e outro tipo de usuario vai poder ter acesso a essas publicacoes apenas pela web. 
como eu consigo inserir? alguem pode me ajudar?

Comment: Minha 'vida toda' escutei para nunca fazer isso (salvar imagem no banco de dados). Mas isso foi a muito tempo, quando a conexão de internet era bem limitada. Embora tenha a questão da escalabilidade também. Não posso dizer se isso é bom porque não conheço o escopo do seu projeto. Existem algumas respostas embaixo. A que melhor adequar, marque como certa, e se possível fala só mais um pouquinho do seu projeto.

Comment: resolveu seu problema ?

Comment: Assim Paulo ( desculpa se eu não marquei vc, sou novo aqui e não sei se tem como marcar) mas assim, o meu projeto tem 3 tabela usuário,órgão e publicação. vamos focar na de publicação ( vou separar em dois comentários pois excedi o limite de caracteres )

Comment: um usuário vai tirar uma foto e colocar uma descrição pra ela, uma categoria e uma localização também ( o horário o sistema pega automaticamente ) . a partir do momento que ele publicar vai para o web service que vai salvar no banco e a qualquer ora uma pessoa pelo  navegador pode ter acesso a essas publicações . e tipo o instagram, entendi? só que mais simples ( já que eu estou aprendendo uma linguagem nova ... então estou fazendo o básico.                                                     ps: se houver erro de acento essas coisas desculpa estou digitando de um teclado do tipo eng

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize o tipo BYTEA que é um array de bytes. 
Quanto a linguagem Lua, não sei te falar, mas no C#, é só passar o `byte[]` como parâmetro normalmente.

Dica: Prefira por usar tabela de imagens separada da tabela de registros, assim você pode inserir várias imagens para o mesmo registro.

Exemplo em C# + ODBC:

```
byte[] Imagem = (arquivo de imagem em bytes);

OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(/*string de conexão*/);
cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO [Tabela]
(coluna_bytea) VALUES (?);";

OdbcParameter[] paramC = new OdbcParameter[1];
paramC[0] = new OdbcParameter("coluna_bytea", OdbcType.Binary);
paramC[0].Value = ((Imagem == null || Imagem.Length == 0 )? null : Imagem);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: boa ideia! obrigado pela dica ! ja com relacao ao tipo se eu colocar uma coluna desse tipo e passar uma imagem ele ja salva?

Comment: Como te falei na resposta, não sei como faz isso na linguagem lua... mas o campo é do tipo array de bytes, pode salvar qualquer arquivo nele, não só imagens, exe, dll, doc, xls, pdf. Então você tem que enviar pro banco um parâmetro do mesmo tipo (array de bytes)

Comment: resposta incompleta e indireta, fora da tag da pergunta.

Comment: @RafaelLemos tanto que ajudou ao membro e foi marcada como resposta, aí aparece você, marca todas as outras como negativo e coloca a sua. Parabéns

Comment: @Ronann Linhalis Tudo bem, não quero desavenças.

Comment: O SOpt é cheio disso, @RafaelLemos. A galera senta o dedo no downvote, mesmo que a pergunta/resposta ajude outros, especialmente os noviços. É uma avaliação que tem como peso a vaidade que mora no universo particular de um grupo.

Answer (score -1):

Para armazenar a foto, quem faz isso é a linguagem de BackEnd, ex: PHP. 
Para fazer o envio...

```
http = require("socket.http")
```

ltn12 = require("ltn12")

```
http.request{
    url = "SEU-SERVIDOR/ARQUIVO.PHP",
    method = "POST",
    headers = {
        ["Content-Type"] =  "multipart/form-data",
        ["Content-Length"] = sizeOfFile
    },
    source = ltn12.source.file(io.open(pathToLocalFile)),
    sink = ltn12.sink.table(response_body)
}
print(response_body[1])
```

Comment: resposta incompleta e indireta, fora da tag da pergunta.

Answer (score -1):

Eu posso te ajudar na parte de criar a tabela mySql.
Da uma olha no código abaixo,

```
  create table imagens (
        imagem_id        tinyint(3)  not null default '0',
        imagem_type      varchar(25) not null default ' ',
        image            LONGBLOB    not null,
        imagem_size      varchar(25) not null default ' ',
        imagem_catg      varchar(25) not null default ' ',
        imagem_name      varchar(50) not null default ' ',
    );
```

Comment: ok amigo, mas assim. a imagem nesse caso vai ficar na coluna imagem do tipo longblob?

Comment: resposta incompleta e indireta, fora da tag da pergunta.

Answer (score -1):

**Segundo a [documentação do PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/datatype-binary.html)**

Você pode usar o formato **bytea** para gravar  binários:

```
CREATE TABLE images (imgname text, img bytea);
```

**Criando [tabela em Lua:](https://github.com/LuaDist/luasql-postgresql/blob/master/tests/example.lua)**

```
require"luasql.postgres"                       -- carrega a biblioteca postgres
env = assert (luasql.postgres())               -- cria a variável de ambiente
con = assert (env:connect("luasql-test"))      -- conectando ao banco
res = assert (con:execute[[ CREATE TABLE images (imgname text, img bytea); ]])     -- criando tabela binária
```

**Gravando dados [binários:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-GENFILE-TABLE)**

```
res = assert (con:execute[[ INSERT INTO images values ('imagem.jpg', pg_read_file('/caminho/da/imagem.jpg')::bytea) ); ]])
```

Comment: Moderador, me diga o que está errado nesta resposta.