# Problema com Salvar imagem em banco de dados MySQL C#

Tags: c#

Olá!

Ao salvar a imagem, ao invés de ir o arquivo pro banco de dados com o tamanho certinho, vai o seguinte:
[image: Aparece isso no banco]

Código dentro do Visual Studio:

```
        private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        dialog.Filter = "JPEG Files(*.jpg)|*.jpg";

        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string foto = dialog.FileName.ToString();
            textBox1.Text = foto;
            pictureBox1.ImageLocation = foto;

        }
    }

  private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] img = new byte[0];

        FileStream Stream = new FileStream(textBox1.Text, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        BinaryReader binary = new BinaryReader(Stream);
        img = binary.ReadBytes((int)Stream.Length);


        string comando = "INSERT INTO ibagen(img) VALUES('" + img.ToArray() + "')";
        MySqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = comando;


        try
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Imagem enviada com sucesso!");
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }

    }
```

Não sei mais o que fazer, tentei converter a "imagem" que foi pro banco de dados, e dá nisso aqui:

[image: Dá nisso]

Comment: também tem um exemplo aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/207207/69359

Comment: Não, nada a ver com o primeiroi

Comment: Meu erro é completamente diferente.

Comment: tem razão, veja se o exemplo linkado te ajuda

Comment: Aí que ta, o meu erro é exatamente esse, a imagem não vai pro banco de dados, não sei porque ;(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Com um botão você carrega o arquivo no `PictureBox`, certo? Então, na hora de salvar, você pode pegar a `Image` do `PictureBox`, converte-la em `byte[]` e executar a query passando como parâmetro.

Exemplo:

Método para converter `Image` em `byte[]`:

```
public static byte[] ConvertImageToByte(System.Drawing.Image image)
{
    if (image == null)
        return null;

    byte[] data;

    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(image);
        bmp.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        data = stream.ToArray();
    }

    return data;
}
```

O seu evento, seria assim:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    byte[] bImage = ConvertImageToByte(pictureBox1.Image);

    string sql = "INSERT INTO ibagen (img) VALUES (@img)";

    using (MysqlConnection con = new MysqlConnection("string de conexao"))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql,con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("img", OdbcType.Binary); //Aqui trocar pelo type do Mysql
            cmd.Parameters["img"].Value = bImage;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

> Lembrando que é apenas um exemplo. Não há tratamento de exceções, e o código SQL não deveria estar na tela.

Comment: No VALUES (@img), o que eu faço?

Comment: Muito obrigado! me salvou demais